# I want to write a decorator that will divide numbers into tens and hundreds. For example: 1000000 -> 1 000 000

Tags: python

My problem is that I don't understand how to prescribe it correctly.

```
def one(func):
    def two():
        a = (f'{func:,}'.replace(',', ' '))
    return two

@one
def test():
    b = 1000
test()
```

Is there something we need to add or remove on the contrary?

Comment: What does `divide digits by a number` mean?

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking but also does seem like something any tutorial on how to write a decorator should answer.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator#:~:text=Decorating%20Functions%20with%20Parameters

Comment: I get the following error: "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to function.__format__". I understand that the problem is in this place, but I don't know how to fix it correctly.

Comment: That entire f-string has nothing to do with dividing a number

Comment: I need the number to be divided into tens and hundreds by type: 1000000 -> 1,000,000

Comment: So you're asking how to format a number with thousand separators? what does that need a decorator for? What have you tried/researched?

Comment: @Sayse I want to divide a large number of numbers at once into hundreds and tens, so as not to constantly write string formatting

Comment: I assume that with `a = (f'{func:,}'.replace(',', ' '))` you are trying to format the integer with a comma and then replace that comma with a space, but you're overcomplicating a simple problem, you don't need decorators for this. And it doesn't seem like you fully understand decorators

Comment: @Daviid I understand how to divide a number. I just wanted to conduct an experiment and write a decorator for this, so as not to constantly write everything through the "f" line

Comment: Its really unclear what the expected output is here, is `test()` supposed to return  `1 000`? a decorator is not going to be able to manipulate a random variable inside of a function

Comment: @Sayse So what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, you haven't described the problem well enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decorator typically works with the returning value of the function it decorates, so for your purpose you should make the decorated function return a number, make the wrapper function call the decorated function and convert the returning number into a string of the desired format and return it, and make the decorator return the wrapper function:

```
def to_thousands(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return f'{func(*args, **kwargs):,}'.replace(',', ' ')
    return wrapper

@to_thousands
def test():
    return 1234567

print(test())
```

This outputs:

```
1 234 567
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand what the mistake is!!

Answer (score 1):

I still think you're overcomplicating. Why store the `a` and `b` variables?

What's the difference between having to write the f-string, having to write the decorator and having to write a function call?

```py
def separate_with_space(integer):
    return f"{integer:,}".replace(","," ")

print(separate_with_space(1))
print(separate_with_space(10))
print(separate_with_space(100))
print(separate_with_space(1000))
print(separate_with_space(10000))
print(separate_with_space(100000))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me figure out my problem!!